# Python Requests - missing element value

Tags: python, html, forms, python-requests

Suppose I have the following HTML input element within a form:

```
<input name="title_input" type="text" id="missing_value" title="Title">
```

If I want to submit a POST:

```
s = requests.Session()
s.get(url)
postResult = s.post(url, {'title_input':'This Is the Name of the Title'})
```

Even though the element has a missing value attribute, will this POST still work correctly?

I.e. will Python append `value="This Is The Name of the Title"` in the element even though it's missing from the original HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Even though the element has a missing value attribute, will this POST still work correctly?

Yes It will. POST request will be done without obtaining HTML at all

You don't need this line for POST request

```
s.get(url)
```

> I.e. will Python append value="This Is The Name of the Title" in the element

No Python will not append anything. Python even will not analyze get content (if get request is done)

It just open tcp connection and send data.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't explained what that HTML is or how it relates to the Python code, but in any case the HTML doesn't seem to have anything to do with anything. The POST request is made by the requests module, not by HTML, so it gets its value from whatever you put into the parameters to the `post()` call.

Comment: Why would you downvote my question? The HTML input element I listed was enough information to understand my question. I was simply asking about the value attribute in particular.